# Optimization problems over the Integers

Tags: mathematical-optimization, diophantine-equations

Should be an easy question. How can I define a function which gets only integers in a form that I can use to find max and min for instance?

Example:

> Find the Max of the expression `(3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1)` where n ∈ Integers

Comment: `f[x_Integer] := x`? `f[1]` will work while `f[1.]` won't.

Comment: You can use `f[x_Integer]:=...` but that won't help you to solve diophantine eqs in the general case. Please show what kind of problems you need to solve

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I used this expression but couldn't find min and max of this: (3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1).

Comment: `i = IntegerPart; sol = NMaximize[{(3 i@ n + 4)/(2  i@n + 1), n > 1}, n]; i@n /. sol[[2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diophantine problems are tough and there is no silver bullet. In your example this works:

```
i = IntegerPart; 
sol = NMaximize[{(3 i@ n + 4)/(2 i@n + 1), n > 1}, n]; 
i@n /. sol[[2]]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: NMaximize[{(3 IntegerPart@n + 4)/(2 IntegerPart@n + 1), n > 1}, 
   n] // First

Answer (score 3):

Bounding the range of n resolves the issue with `Maximize`

```
Maximize[{(3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1), Element[n, Integers], -100 <= n <= 100}, n]
```

> {4, {n -> 0}}

Or,

```
Maximize[{(3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1), -100 <= n <= 100}, n, Integers]
```

> {4, {n -> 0}}

Any large value for the range bound will work since

```
Limit[(3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1), n -> #] & /@ {Infinity, -Infinity}
```

> {3/2, 3/2}

```
DiscretePlot[
 (3 n + 4)/(2 n + 1),
 {n, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]